# Color running over text in multirow column

Tags: tables, color

I have a simple table with 2 multirow cells. However when I apply background color, it covers
the lower portion of the multirow cells and cuts through the middle of my text entry which is obviously not what I want. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Also notice that I'm using \vspace to move my text entry 1mm up in the multirow cells because it wasn't centered. It was closer to the lower border. There is probably a better way of doing this. Below is my code and output table that I'm getting with it:[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.92,0.95,0.86}
\arrayrulecolor{white}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
{ >{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{79pt}
>{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{145pt}|| 
>{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{79pt}
>{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{145pt} }
\multicolumn{2}{>{\cellcolor{mycolor}}l||}{\textbf{STUDENT DATA}}& 
\multirow{2}{*}{{\vspace{-1mm}\textbf{Name:}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\vspace{-1mm}MyName}\\
\textbf{E-mail:} & test@example.com &  & \\
\hline \hline
\textbf{Date:} & 21.3.2011 & \textbf{Student ID:} & 3836127\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the lower cells of the `\multirow` are filled after the text was typeset. To solve this you need to place the text in the lower cells and raise it, e.g. using `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.92,0.95,0.86}
\arrayrulecolor{white}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
{ >{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{79pt}
>{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{145pt}|| 
>{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{79pt}
>{\columncolor{mycolor}}b{145pt} }
\multicolumn{2}{>{\cellcolor{mycolor}}l||}{\textbf{STUDENT DATA}}&&\\
\textbf{E-mail:} & test@example.com & \raisebox{1.6ex}[1.6ex]{\textbf{Name:}} & \raisebox{1.6ex}[1.6ex]{MyName}\\
\hline \hline
\textbf{Date:} & 21.3.2011 & \textbf{Student ID:} & 3836127\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Please also make sure to provide *minimal* examples. Half the code here is not required to demonstrate the issue and therefore finding the issue takes longer as necessary.

Comment: You can avoid the use of `\raisebox` by placing the `\multirow` commands in the last row, and using a negative first argument: `\multicolumn{2}{>{\cellcolor{mycolor}}l||}{\textbf{STUDENT DATA}} & & \\textbf{E-mail:} & test@example.com & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Name:}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{MyName} \\`

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo. I don't know `multirow` very well and therefore went for `\raisebox`.