# How can I make a table with colored rows without the column headings being drawn over?

Tags: tables, multirow

I have been trying to make this table[image: table]

but I have a problem with the first row, the text "P kanal" and "Q kanal" aren't in the center here is what I get

[image: table 2]

The code I used:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline
\hline
\rowcolor[RGB]{77,77,77}\color{white}\multirow{1}{}{Modulacijska} & \color{white}\multirow{1}{}{Biti na izlazu} & \color{white}\multirow{2}{}{\emph{I} kanal} & \color{white}\multirow{2}{}{\emph{Q} kanal} \\ 
\rowcolor[RGB]{77,77,77}\color {white} tehnika & \color{white} kanalnog prepletača & & \\
\hline
\hline
BSPK & $x_{0}$ & $x_{0}$ & - \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: your code please upload

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please show what your tried so far in the forma of a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Does `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\rowcolor{gray} text & \multirow{2}{*}{covered text} \\
\rowcolor{gray} text & \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\rowcolor{gray} text & \\
\rowcolor{gray} text & \multirow{-2}{*}{correctly shown text} \\
\end{tabular
}
\end{document}`help you?

Comment: Probably related: [Color running over text in multirow column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13971/134144)

Comment: I have uploaded the code I used.

Comment: With multirow you need to move the chopped text to the second row, with a negative rows parameter.

Comment: All your `\multirow` commands are missing the second argument. You can not leave that pair of `{}` empty. Depending on the desired output, use a width  `*` or `=` there.

Comment: @Sabina: Can you choose a better title for your question? Something that is specific to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected version of your code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c} 
\hline \hline 
\rowcolor[RGB]{77,77,77}
\color{white} Modulacijska 
  & \color{white} Biti na izlazu 
    & 
      &  \\ 
\rowcolor[RGB]{77,77,77}
\color{white} tehnika
  &\color{white} kanalnog prepletača 
    & \color{white}\multirow{-2}{*}{\emph{I} kanal} 
      & \color{white}\multirow{-2}{*}{\emph{Q} kanal}\\
      \hline \hline 
BSPK 
  & $x_{0}$ 
    & $x_{0}$ 
      & - \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

No `\multirow`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline\hline
\rowcolor[RGB]{77,77,77}\color{white}\splitcell{Modulacijska \\ tehnika} &
\color{white}\splitcell{Biti na izlazu \\ kanalnog prepletača} &
\color{white}\emph{I} kanal &
\color{white}\emph{Q} kanal \\
\hline \hline
BSPK & $x_{0}$ & $x_{0}$ & -
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd remove the double `\hline` commands: the big gray bar just serves the purpose. Actually I'd avoid the big bar, but that's personal preference.

Comment: Thank you for your advice

Comment: I also prefer you solution over `multirow`. However, `\makecell{}` does the same and has particular features: it applies line spread found in regular paragraphs, and `\makecell{}` is not affected by `arraystretch`, which sometimes helps with visual distinction of cells containing group of data. I think it's not possible to do that with regular `tabular`, is it?

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.11).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\doublerulesepcolor{white}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\hline\hline
\RowStyle[color=white,rowcolor=[RGB]{77,77,77}]{}
\Block{}{Modulacijska \\ tehnika} &
\Block{}{Biti na izlazu \\ kanalnog prepletača} &
\emph{I} kanal &
\emph{Q} kanal \\
\hline \hline
BSPK & $x_{0}$ & $x_{0}$ & -
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]